# Diffing two text files while excluding leading spaces and trailing commas

Tags: awk

Is there any way to check if the file1 has any different content than file2 excluding leading spaces and trailing commas.

File1:

```
1  
  2  
3,  
4  
5
```

File2:

```
1  
2  
3  
5
```

If I run:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

it is returning 2 3, 4. But we need it to return only  4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to know if they differ or not, without the need for differing content, you can `diff`, with process substitution:

```
diff -wq <(sed 's/,$//' file1) <(sed 's/,$//' file2)
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Files differ!"
```

Comment: I use GIT bash and unfortunately it is not allowing process substitution. Diff, Comm commands are throwing errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
diff -U0 <(sed 's/^[ ]*//;s/,$//' file1) <(sed 's/^[ ]*//;s/,$//' file2) | sed '/@@/d;s/^.//;1,2d'
```

`diff -U0 <(sed 's/^[ ]*//;s/,$//' file1) <(sed 's/^[ ]*//;s/,$//' file2)` will result in:
The option `-U0` tells `diff` to print `0` common lines before and after the difference.

```
--- /dev/fd/63  2017-05-16 14:37:00.565871029 -0700
+++ /dev/fd/62  2017-05-16 14:37:00.565871029 -0700
@@ -4 +3,0 @@
-4
```

Sending this output to `sed` and stripping the headers and removing the `diff` marker will result in `4`.

`/^@@/d` - means remove any lines that start with `@@`. This is useful if there are multiple non-contiguous difference.

`s/^.//` - means remove the first character. The first character can be `' '`, common to both files, `'-'` only on first file, `'+'` only on second file.

`1,2d` - means delete the first 2 lines.

Or if you don't like patch format difference, you can run

```
diff <(sed 's/^[ ]*//;s/,$//' file1) <(sed 's/^[ ]*//;s/,$//' file2) | sed '/^[^<>|]/d;s/^..//'
```

The above commands didn't work because you are running Windows.

Using the tool that you have:

```
awk '{split(tolower($0),b,",");split(b[1],b," ")} FNR==NR{a[b[1]]++;next}!(b[1] in a)' file2 file1
```

`tolower(string)` - will return a copy of string in lowercase. this will make the comparison case insensitive. The original value in `$0` is intact.

`split(string,array,fs)` will split `string` into `array` starting at index 1 using `fs` as separator.

Comment: Thank You!!! but it is throwing error:   sh.exe": cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented
sh.exe": cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented
diff: missing operand
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.

Comment: Is there anyway to specify exclude comms and white spaces in awk?  awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1

Comment: @NagmaFan - It looks like you are running Windows. Process substitution is only available on *nix flavors. Bash or any shells on Windows don't support process substitution.

Comment: @NagmaFan - I added `awk` solution.

Comment: Alvits, Thank you soomuch. It works like charm. We really appreciate your help!

Comment: Alvits,  Is there a way to make case insensitive comparison of lines?  Thanks.

Comment: @NagmaFan - yes, you can either convert to lowercase for comparison `tolower($0)` or convert to uppercase for comparison `toupper($0)`. When displaying, do you prefer to display the original case or okay to display the all lowercase?

Comment: Thanks Alvits. We would like to display in original case :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could also add the unwanted prefix/suffix to the record separator:

```
awk -v RS='[\n ,]+' 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thanks user000001. We will check.